# Different colour between series VBA Scatter Graph

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I have the following macro which plots a Scatter graph for three columns. One column (AL13, downwards) is on the x axis. How do I get it to plot the other two columns (AK and AM) onto the same scatter? Also in different colour to each other? Thank You

```
Sub Graphing()

        Set rng4 = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("AP13"), Range("AV33"))

With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rng4.Left, Width:=rng4.Width, Top:=rng4.Top, Height:=rng4.Height)
    .Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .Chart.HasLegend = False
    .Chart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 18
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Size = 18
    Set srs = .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    srs.Values = Range(Range("AK13"), Range("AK13").End(xlDown))
    srs.XValues = Range(Range("AL13"), Range("AL13").End(xlDown))
    srs.Values = Range(Range("AM13"), Range("AM13").End(xlDown)) 

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will repost the code that I revised for you above, thanks for crediting me :)

```
Sub Graphing()
'Declare all the variables to be used:'
Dim rng4 as Range
Dim srs as Series
Dim cht as Chart
Dim xVals as Range
Dim srsVals as Range 

'Set the chart's data range:'
Set rng4 = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("AP13"), Range("AV33"))

'Set the range variable to contain the series values'
' You can later modify this to include any number of columns, and the '
'  loop structure below will add each column as a series to the chart.'
Set srsVals = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("AL13"),Range("AM13").End(xlDown))

'Set the cht variable:'
Set cht= ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rng4.Left, Width:=rng4.Width, Top:=rng4.Top, Height:=rng4.Height).Chart

'Set the Range variable for xValues:
Set xVals = Range(Range("AK13"),Range("AK13").End(xlDown))

'Format the chart and add series to the chart by iterating over the columns in srsVals:'
With cht
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .HasLegend = False
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 18
    .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Size = 18

    'Create the series in a loop
    For c = 1 to srsVal.Columns.Count
        Set srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With srs
            .Values = xVals
            .XValues = Range(srsVals.Columns(c).Address)
            .Name = "Series " & c '<-- Modify as needed.'
        End With
    Next

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I set the series as two separate series then it will plot both and give them different colours. Not sure if it is the most efficient way of doing it but it works.

```
    Sub Graphing()
    'Declare all the variables to be used:'
    Dim rng4 as Range
    Dim srs as Series
    Dim cht as Chart
    Dim xVals as Range
    Dim srsVals as Range 

    'Set the chart's data range:'
    Set rng4 = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("AP13"), Range("AV33"))

    'Set the range variable to contain the series values'
    ' You can later modify this to include any number of columns, and the '
    '  loop structure below will add each column as a series to the chart.'
    Set srsVals = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("AL13"),Range("AM13").End(xlDown))

    'Set the cht variable:'
    Set cht= ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rng4.Left, Width:=rng4.Width, Top:=rng4.Top, Height:=rng4.Height).Chart

    'Set the Range variable for xValues:
    Set xVals = Range(Range("AK13"),Range("AK13").End(xlDown))

    'Format the chart and add series to the chart by iterating over the columns in srsVals:'
    With cht
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .HasLegend = False
        .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 18
        .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Size = 18

        'Create the series in a loop
        For c = 1 to srsVal.Columns.Count
            Set srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With srs
                .Values = xVals
                .XValues = Range(srsVals.Columns(c).Address)
                .Name = "Series " & c '<-- Modify as needed.'
            End With
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks correct to me, although you can actually just use `Set srs = .Chart...` for both, no need to also use `srs2`  *unless* you need both Series stored in memory (to do a comparison, computation, etc.).  If you want, I can edit your answer to be a little more efficient, but the code you have provided looks correct.

Comment: Yes please, that would be great. Efficient ways will be useful as I have added titles etc and it soon, although works fine, looked clunky.

Comment: I have submitted an edit to your code, it will be available after it has been reviewed by some people with more reputation points than me :)

Comment: Mary, looks like my edit has been accepted. You can review now!

Comment: @DavidZemens Can you put this down as your answer please. My solution was essentially a re-hash of something you had written previously. So please re-submit as an answer and I will approve it. Thanks. If you are knowledgable of Solver then I would appreciate it if you can have a look at the Solver problem I have posted. Thanks again.